# Shortcut key for presentation mode in Jupyter

Tags: jupyter-notebook, reveal.js, rise

I'm trying to make presentation slides from Jupyter Notebook but there is no button to begin presentation mode. So, I'd like to know if there is any shortcut to start the presentation or any way to make that button appear. BTW, I use Python2.7 and already installed RISE. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My issue was I tried to enable the "Enter RISE" button. So, to fix my issue, I used `conda install -c damianavila82 rise` instead of `pip install RISE` (I normally use pip to install new Python library, anyway).

However, if you are looking for a shortcut for the presentation mode you can try "Atl + r" for entering and exiting RISE. I'm using Windows10, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

## The `conda` way

You can **either** install RISE with `conda` with

```sh
conda install -c damianavila82 rise
```

as already mentioned [in your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44613934/674064). This will install **and** set up Jupyter and RISE so that you can use RISE from Jupyter.

## The `pip`+`jupyter-nbextension` way

**Or** you can install RISE with `pip` like you originally did and then make Jupyter aware of it with

```
jupyter-nbextension install rise --py --sys-prefix
jupyter-nbextension enable rise --py --sys-prefix
```

Apparently, the `jupyter-nbextension install` step copies the required JavaScript and CSS files from where `pip` placed them to where `Jupyter` can find them, while the `jupyter-nbextension install` step tells Jupyter to actually use them and RISE.

Both ways (and a third one using the RISE source code repository) are documented at https://damianavila.github.io/RISE/installation.html

Comment: Those who want to use `pipenv` to install `RISE` (or other Juypter extensions) may be interested in my question [How should Jupyter extensions be installed and enabled for being reproducible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48623274/674064)